# Book about an engineer who travels into a medieval time/world with magic and gods, becomes part of a magic priesthood

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, engineering

It's a book, probably written in the late 90's early 2000's. And, it's about a time traveling engineer (not [Conrad Stargard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard)) who travels back in time to a medieval world divided into different kingdoms. I think it turns out to be an another world. There is magic too, which uses something called mana to heal, among other things. You collect it by killing people or creatures. He starts to introduce industrialization, guns, and the like. He becomes part of a magic priesthood.

He pisses everyone off because he uproots the class system that was in place.

There are gods, but they don't play a big role.

I read it at my public library in Columbus Ga

Comment: The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: For example, was this a book? A movie? A comic book? A cartoon? Web serial? Webcomic? When did you read it?

Comment: It's a book about two years ago. It was probably written in the early 2000's, tho no later than the 90's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could it be:

1. *Inversions* from Iain M. Banks, 1998
2. *Sword of the Bright Lady* from M.C. Planck, 2014
3. *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court* from Mark Twain, 1889

EDIT:

OP confirmed: it is *Sword of the Bright Lady*

Comment: Two things. First, split your answers up into separate answers so that it can be marked which one is correct (unless you think they're mixing up details from different books). Secondly, you need to describe *why* these would match.

Comment: Of the three, *Sword of the Bright Lady* is the best match, but looks to have been published in 2014, which is 20-30 years too late.

Comment: So, which of the three was it?

Comment: Sword of the bright lady

Comment: Personally, I like your answer better. Did you realize it before you saw William's post?

Comment: No, but his answer didn't say which one it was so I made my own answer. But, than I thought it might be poor etiquette to snake his answer.

Comment: @JoeGarcia: It's a bit of a grey area. Some people will just edit the info into the existing answer. Personally, I think that people who only post a title and nothing else pretty much forfeit their right to having the right answer, although I'll certainly give them credit. Should you choose to do so, you can accept your own answer to your question 48 hours after asking, which is in another 41 hours.

Comment: How much salt. The OP would have to look up the books anyway since the sinopse was basically already known to him, therefore copy pasting them into my answer would be naught but waste of time from me and from the others who might read the three walls of text.

Answer (score 5):

[Sword of the Bright Lady, From M.C planck](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616149884)

> A misplaced act of decency lands him in a brawl with an arrogant nobleman and puts him under a death sentence. In desperation he agrees to be drafted into an eternal war, serving as a priest of the Bright Lady, Goddess of Healing. But when Marcius, god of war, offers the only hope of a way home to his wife, Christopher pledges to him instead, plunging the church into turmoil and setting him on a path of violence and notoriety.
>
> To win enough power to open a path home, this mild-mannered mechanical engineer must survive duelists, assassins, and the never-ending threat of monsters, with only his makeshift technology to compete with swords and magic.
>
> But the gods and demons have other plans. Christopher's fate will save the world... or destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

[Portals of Infinity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MKSLRH0) by John Van Stry is what you're looking for.

> William is just your typical engineer fresh out of college with a
>   stressful job, a boring life, and not a lot of prospects of anything
>   better in the future.
>
> Until one weekend while hiking in the woods he stumbles across a
>   portal to another time, or perhaps another place. The more he
>   investigates this new world the more he realizes that it may just be
>   able to offer him a lot more than the one he's been living in.
>
> However, there are forces at work beyond anything that Will has ever
>   come across before and the local Goddess seems to have taken a liking
>   to him. Will may soon find himself getting an offer and cannot afford
>   to refuse.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm afraid the OP has already confirmed the book they're looking for, and it's not this one. This answer can stay - it's useful in case someone else *is* looking for this book - but you need to provide some sort of plot summary and explain why it matches the criteria in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [The Wiz Biz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002AOO3FM) by Rick Cook.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. You should add some detail to your answer to explain *why* you believe this to match OP's criteria.

Comment: No "mana" in that series.  And you don't have to kill people or creatures to gain magical power.  The stories in that book are about a programmer who gets shanghaied into a place with magic.  He creates a "magic compiler" and writes spells like you can write a program.  He didn't have to kill anyone to gain magical power.

Comment: And, no guns in the Rick Cook series you linked to.

Comment: @JRE it's been a long time since I read this, so I mainly remembered "engineer traveling to medieval world".